# How do I add a domain user to a group on a non-domain server?

Tags: active-directory, user-management, groups

If we are running a server that is not attached to the domain, how would I go about adding a domain user to a local group on that server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't. There has to be  a trust between the computer and the domain (aka joining the computer to the domain) to be able to authenticate domain users locally.

Now for something practical:

You have two options 1) create a local user with the same username and password as the domain user, and add that local user to the local group. 2) Join the machine to the domain.

Comment: So simply adding a local user with the same name and password is sufficient to create trust (in this instance)?

Comment: It's not so much creating a trust as having your username and ntlm hash match ... it's more of a hacky work around than anything really.

Comment: Correct. The domain user tries to connect, Kerberos won't be tried, so unless you have GPOs that prevent clients from trying to authenticate via down-level protocols, the machine will try NTLM. If they match, then you're in without having to type anything.